# Visual studio 2013 no publish options other than custom

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, publishing, azure-sdk-.net

My windows system has Visual studio 2013 with Update 5 and Azure Tools 2.6 installed. I was till some time back, able to right click on the project in the solution explorer, click Publish and able to select a Publish target like Microsoft Azure Web Apps:
[image]

But now, the options do not show up anymore and the only option available is Custom:
[image]

I am not sure when the options disappeared. How can I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your VS is connected to your Azure Subscription (Server tab, something with "Azure (yoursubscriptionemail@domain.com)").

Also, since version 2.7 of Azure Tools, the deployment of web apps have changed a bit (publish target should read "Microsoft Azure App Service" instead of "Microsoft Azure Web Apps", and a few new options).
You can try to update your Azure Tools (version 2.8.2 as of this writing), the easiest way to do that is to run Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Comment: @Phani I'm pretty sure that as soon as author's VS is properly connected to Azure, he will be able to get the options back.

Comment: I am connected to a subscription. But that did not bring the options back.

Comment: Edited, should try to update Azure Tools. From experience, sometimes MS change the API and some functionality of older versions of Azute Tools stop working.

Comment: I have another system with pretty much the same configuration and having Azure tools 2.6 and it shows the option to publish to a website. I don't think it is an Azure tools issue. Some of my code is dependent on the Azure tools version which might break if I update the tools. So don't want to change it unless that is the issue for sure.

Comment: Updating the Azure SDK to 2.9 from here resolved this issue: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/
Got the idea from this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705408/microsoft-azure-app-service-target-not-appearing-in-visual-studio-2015-while-c