# "Microsoft Azure App Service" target not appearing in visual studio 2015 while clicking on Publish

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to run the Xamarin.Android app from Microsoft Azure Guides.

According to the guide I am supposed to right-click on the Service project and Rebuild, after that on clicking Publish I get the Publish Target window but there is no target of Azure App Service. I only get Target of Azure Web Apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the project to which you refer is the "QuickStart" server-side project that is downloaded and named *yoursite*-Runtime.zip.  When unpacked, you get a folder *yoursite_AppService* and *yoursite*.sln in the file.

When you right-click and select Publish, you should see the following picture as the pop-up:

[image: Publish Website Dialog]

If this is not the case, then there is something at issue with your install of Visual Studio 2015 - perhaps an additional plugin or an older version of Azure SDK?  Try updating the Azure SDK as a starting point.

Answer (score 7):

Updating the Azure SDK was the solution for me. The following page has all the downloads, select your visual studio version to the left

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

VS2015 Direct link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518003&clcid=0x409