# Microsoft azure web apps not listing in publish target list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35705408/2794391) and also various smiler post to get rid of the issue I am facing from last 2 days, finally I have to post this.

Here what I am getting when I am going to publish my project:

[image]

I don't know why the option of azure web App is not listing which was in the list 2 day back.

[image]

I have updated azure sdk installed also I have updated my visual studio 2015.
Please let me know if needed any other information from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure App Service == Web Apps / API Apps / Logic Apps / Mobile Apps.

Comment: ....thanks for this swift reply now its working but previously when I was publishing the project there was no resources which I can use for the same.